# Dystopian novel about vampires or zombies (can't remember which). Kids are raised away from their families

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I read a book several years ago (2003-ish) which was about a group of survivors that were living after a vampire or zombie apocalypse (I can't remember which).

The children were kept secluded from the adults, possibly in a school building, and on their 18th birthday were sent to live with their families and told the truth about the zombies/vampires.

I recall that one of the characters couldn't see very well and was in desperate need of glasses.

Answer (score 7):

The timeframe isn't quite right (it was published in 2010), and a few other details are off as well, but the general gist of this sounds like [The Passage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passage_(Cronin_novel)) by Justin Cronin.  The novel starts early as the vampires start to take over, and then jumps to a situation very much like you remember.  It's a small group of survivors.

Children are raised communally and told the truth at the age of eight (not eighteen), as described in [this interview](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=127790281):

> This is a kind of deep greed that they commit, because they fail to notice that we are already immortal, because the future we do not personally live to see is the one our children live in. The sanctuary is a protective enclave within this colony of survivors. It sits at the center. Its an old elementary school. It's fortified. It is the last retreat in the event that the Colony is invaded. And all the children in the Colony live there until the age of eight, and they live in a bubble of not knowing.
>
> The world in which they live is one that is so potentially psychologically traumatic that the founders of this society have decided, well, we'll give people eight years not to know the truth. And so the children live there sort of sealed away, not just from other people, but from the knowledge of what the world really is. And one person, who's called Teacher, it's her job when you turn eight to tell you what the truth is, so that you dont hate your parents for it, actually. So she bears the collective trauma of this resentment.

A character with progressive vision loss is Galen Strauss described (in the Wiki's ["Characters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Passage_characters) page) as:

> A member of the First Colony watch, Galen experiences progressive loss of vision—he suffers from severe glaucoma, which renders him almost entirely blind.

Comment: Yesss! That's it! Thanks.

Comment: @Candice Glad I could help.  When you get a chance, please click the checkmark (near the up and downvote icons) beside the answer, which marks the answer as accepted.

Comment: And the menaces are technically vampires, but in many ways they act more like zombies, which makes your confusion there understandable.

Comment: The great news is that the second and third parts of this trilogy are out now, too.